# Is it possible to separate command arguments in eclipse with bars?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

What I'm asking is, instead of spaces separating arguments can you have bars do it for eclipse arguments?

So instead of passing everything as one word like
    somethingOne somethingTwo somethingThree
you could do it like

```
something one|something two|something three|
```

instead?

Comment: Where? You mean in the run configuration dialog? i.e. arguments to your java program?

Comment: @aioobe Yes in the run configurations

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use bars, but you can do

```
"something one" "something two" "something three"
```

if you want to include spaces in your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your Main method will accept it as a single argument.

After receiving it in main method you can split it with bar.

Comment: No, it will be received as `something`, `one|something`, `two|something`, `three|`.

Comment: Yes, if OP's "Something One" is actual data... and not for sake of explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You can only separate arguments by space and this limit is posed by Java not by Eclipse.
I think your issue is that you want to pass arguments which have space in them. If that is the case you can enclose that arguments in double quotations. For your example it would be:

```
"something one" "something two" "something three"
```

Look at this link for the details of how you can define arguments for a Java program:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think it's a limit posed by Java. I think it's a limit of whatever launches the java program. In this case Eclipse.

Comment: Of course the luncher could in theory be able to have its own syntax for accepting the parameters but hey why reinventing the wheel again?
I am sure this is the question the Eclipse developers will ask themselves when they think about this problem. When Java has a support for it and it works fine there is no reason to define a new syntax which could make developers even more confused.

Comment: I'm not saying that the launcher has any reason to invent a new syntax. I'm just saying that your answer is misleading when you state *"[...] this limit is posed by Java not by Eclipse"*. Java accepts a `String[]` and nothing limits that from including spaces. Besides, I don't understand what you mean by *"Java has support for it"*. Are you referring to the `java` command?

Comment: Yes I meant Java command and you are right. I should better say the OS shell and most operating systems separate arguments by space. :) 
Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. But this will be read as a **single parameter**. So you have to split it by "|".

Make sure that whole String is enclosed with `"` (double quotes).

```
String[] data=null;
if(args.length>0){
  data = args[0].split("|");
}
```

Then the String array `data` contains `{"something one","something two","something three"}`

But I'm not quite sure why are you trying to do this.

Comment: I want to pass arguments with spaces is why I'm doing this

Comment: You **can** pass arguments with spaces using double quotes.